# TCL encoding for type for large number of decimal places

Tags: encoding, tcl

I simply want to know what format I need to use to display irrational numbers to decimal places greater than 16 as per the Unicode standard.

I’ve tried things like:

```
set var [expr [format %.1000f 1] / [format %.1000f 9]]
```

And still only get 1/9 to 16 decimal places.

I need to increment 1/x for x < 1000 and see all the decimal places (up to at a minimum 1000).

Any tips ?

Comment: Tcl defaults to using IEEE double precision floats, so what you want can't be done (the information is _definitely_ lost) with a simple approach. You need an exact arithmetic package; I believe there's one available (I'll look it up later if nobody else helps you first).

Answer (score 0):

Tcl's native floating point math uses IEEE double precision floats; those only have around 15 or so meaningful significant figures (there's effectively 53 bits in the mantissa). Instead, you need to use an arbitrary precision floating point arithmetic package. Tcllib has one, [`math::bigfloat`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/math/bigfloat.html):

```
package require math::bigfloat
namespace import math::bigfloat::*

# How many digits do we want
set places 1000

set x [fromstr 1.0 $places]
set y [fromstr 9.0 $places]
set z [div $x $y]
puts [tostr $z]
```

You can also use [`math::exact`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/tcllib-1-18/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/math/exact.html) from Tcllib, which does things a little differently internally (you specify the precision you want in the output *at the end*):

```
package require math::exact
namespace import math::exact::exactexpr

# This package uses *binary* precision, not decimal
set precision [expr {ceil(log(10)/log(2) * 1000)}]

set x [[exactexpr 1] ref]
set y [[exactexpr 9] ref]
set z [[exactexpr {$x / $y}] ref]
$z asFloat $precision
```

The `ref` stuff is to do with reference count management because expression objects are internally non-trivial.

Comment: Thank you again @Donal_Fellows ! I am using an older version of TCL in a closed system so I couldn’t download the math pack but I managed to run the script using an online IDE and it worked great.